# Casting raw Map to Map<Object, Object>, will there be any issue?

Tags: java

I need to convert raw `Map` to `Map<string,string>`, and I think I have to first convert the raw map to `Map<Object,Object>` and then convert it again to `Map<String,String>`.

code snippet goes like below.

```
    Map obj1 = new HashMap();
    obj1.put("key1", 1);
    obj1.put("key2", false);
    obj1.put("key3", 3.94f);


    Map<Object, Object> obj2 = obj1;

    Map<String, String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry: obj2.entrySet()) {
        obj.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }
```

I guess it would work in any condition but I want to hear from others about possible danger of this code.(any possiblities for `ClassCastException` for example?)

Please also let me know if you have a better idea.

-- revised code

```
    Map obj1 = new HashMap();
    obj1.put(2, 1);
    obj1.put(true, false);
    obj1.put(4.4f, 3.94f);

    Map<String, String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for (Object k : obj1.keySet()){
        obj.put(k.toString(), obj1.get(k).toString());
    }
```

Since raw Map entries will contain key/value of Objects anyway, I think I don't need temporary `Map<Object,Object>`. Just iterating over each item works well and I don't see any issues so far.

Comment: You are passing in explicit `String` types for both the key and value.  I don't see a problem with this.

Comment: You don't need `obj2`.  You could just write `for(Map.Entry entry : obj1.entrySet())`.  But the best way is to use wildcards - what you have is a `Map<?,?>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You Look out the Definition of `HashMap` in `jdk 1.4` It was earlier Implements using `Object` Class when `generics` Concept not came.

When `generics` is Introduced this `object` is Replaced with `<T>`. But If you Still don't use `Generics` Type Safe then Internally this Statement `new HashMap()` reflects a instance of `<Object, Object>`. Better To use directly a 
a `new HashMap()` is better idea. There should no need of `Map <Object, Object> obj2`.

So, GO For this.. a better approach.

```
Map obj1 = new HashMap();
  obj1.put("key1", 1);
  obj1.put("key2", false);
  obj1.put("key3", 3.94f);


Map<Object, Object> obj2 = obj1;

Map<String, String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();

for (Object obj_Entry : obj1.entrySet()) {
    Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) obj_Entry; // This will Work Fine all Time. 
    obj.put(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will not generate `ClassCastExceptions`. Actually you are not doing any casting here. You just call the toString() method of every key/value pair to make it a string. As long as `toString()` returns a valid value of your objects. Your code will be fine.

But your code may produce `NullPointerExceptions` if your `obj1` contain null keys or objects

```
obj1.put(null, "null value")
```

Also note that some key collisions may occur if `toString()` methods return same `String` value for two keys. This is unlikely but it is possible.